# regex give me output only if iswhitespace character after searching word

Tags: java, regex

Simple question how modify this regex that give me fredro after av. ? now if in my text isn't any whitespace it doesn't work, when i add space it works.
My regex: `((av\.|avenue\.)\s?)(\w.+?\s)`
[example](https://regex101.com/r/sREGmm/4)

And if i add whitespace it [works](https://regex101.com/r/sREGmm/5). So it is  fine but i want when isn't whitespace it works also. Also if the output will be `some text av.fredro.` or `some text av.fredro,` it should give me fredro, but now it isn't. Or if i have:`some text av fredro some text another av example1 text text avenue example2` should give me `fredro,example1,example2`. Any idea? I'm not good in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this regex:

```
\b(avenue|av)\b\.?\s?(\w+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sREGmm/10)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b          # word boundary
(           # start capturing group #1
   avenue   # match "avenue"
   |        # OR
   av       # match "av"
)           # end capturing group #1
\b          # word boundary
\.?         # match an optional literal dot character
\s?         # match an optional whitespace character
(           # start capturing group #2
   \w+      # match one or more word characters
)           # end capturing group #2
```

Comment: If dot is optional as well then use: `(av|avenue)\.?\s?(\w+)`

Comment: I edited my post. I want receive output after "av" or "av." or "av " or "av. " etc , "avenue", "avenue ", "avenue.","avenue. "

Comment: Edit: Unfortunately it still not working correctly. I didn't see but in your example it take to output avenue insted of example2